# How to run electron's unit tests without compiling electron's source code

Tags: testing, electron, specifications

I need a tool to check the compatibility of electron on our platform. Because our operating system and hardware is quite complex and we have all kinds of hardware.
I found a test case for your electron framework that meets our needs. code under the `electron/spec` directory.
The test cases for electron are a separate electron app and I don't know how I can separate the test cases from the electon code repository. I can run the test cases using `npm run test` after compiling electron, can the test cases run if electron is not compiled?

compiled the source code for electon and then went to run the test cases under `electron/spec` using one of the electon I downloaded was able to succeed. But using an uncompiled electon source code, it fails!
Can anyone help me, please?